# How would you parse this HTML table using Python?

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to create a scraping script in Python 2.7.

The request is ok, but I have a hard time trying to parse this table with Beautiful soup. I've tried a lot, and searched a lot on the forum, but nothing works for me, my first time doing this.

Here is the code :

```
 import requests, os 
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  

 url='http://fse.vdkruijssen.eu/ferrylist.php' params={'selectplane':'Cessna 208 Caravan','submit':''}
 response=requests.post(url, data=params) 

 soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html5lib")
 table=soup.find('table')
 print table
```

But this is not returning any table. I'm trying to retrieve the first and the last column at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
```

change the parser to `lxml`

Beautiful Soup supports the HTML parser included in Python’s standard library, but it also supports a number of third-party Python parsers. One is the lxml parser. Depending on your setup, you might install lxml with one of these commands:

```
$ apt-get install python-lxml

$ easy_install lxml

$ pip install lxml
```

By default, BS4 use `lxml` parser.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and precisions !